# CRM Dynamics 2015 Plugin registration Tool crashes on WCF/ASMX service call

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm-2015

Your help will be highly appreciated, I have registered a Plug-in on phone call create in CRM Dynamics 2015, When I debug the plugin using the profiler, the plugin Registration tool stops working as soon as I make a call to the WCF service client method exposed. I have tried with both an ASXM service and a WCF service,i have deployed the service in IIS on the same server CRM is hosted,I tested the service against a console and SOAP UI, everything works fine, the minute I use it kin a Plugin context it crashed the registration tool on service call. There is no error logged in the plugin Registration tool log files, here is my plugin code below

```
 public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity phoneCallEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (phoneCallEntity.LogicalName != "phonecall")
                return;
            //ensure that the Plugin fires on a create operaton
            if (context.MessageName == "Create")
            {
                try
                {
                    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

                        myBinding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IService1";

                        myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

                        myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

                        myBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;

                        myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

                        EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://154.66.196.127/Webservice/ZoiperCallHistory.asmx");

                        ZoiperCallHistorySoapClient client = new ZoiperCallHistorySoapClient(myBinding,endPointAddress);

                        client.Open();



                        CallHistory callHistory = client.GetZoiperCallHistory();

                        client.GetZoiperCallHistory();
```

The code fails on this line :  CallHistory callHistory = client.GetZoiperCallHistory();

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the plugin is registered as isolation "none" (outside the sandbox)?

Comment: I believe that your issue is related to fact that you use IP address instead of FQDN. Recheck this article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the plugin registration tool doesn't go well with debugging web service calls. Try instead using the tracing service to identify errors or to analyze the web service response.

```
ITracingService tracingService =
(ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
```

Comment: Thanks - this showed me the same error I was having was due to a 401 Unauthorized.